# Netty ByteToMessageCodec<ByteBuf> decoding message twice (partially)

Tags: java, netty

I am using the `EmbeddedChannel` to test my `handlers` and `codecs` to process messages in the following format:

```
 +------------+------------------+----------------+      
 |   Header   |  Payload Length  |    Payload     |
 |  16 bytes  |     2 bytes      |  "Some data"   |     
 +------------+------------------+----------------+
```

Firstly, what I want to achieve:

1. Process first 16 bytes by creating an object to store the header details in and add the decoded header object to the `AttributeMap` of the `ChannelHandlerContext` for later use;
2. Wait for/retrieve entire payload data;
3. Have Header object and entire payload as `ByteBuf` available on final handler to route message.

I using the following handlers:

1. `ByteToMessageCodec<ByteBuf>` to extract the header info and add it to the attribute list.
2. `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` to read the payload length and wait for/retrieve entire frame.
3. `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` that will use the header object retrieved from attribute list to route the payload accordingly.

When a message is passed to the `decode` method of the `ByteToMessageCodec`, the header is processed and extracted correctly. I then continue to add the Header object to the `AttributeMap` and add the `ByteBuf` (which has a readableBytes = 2 bytes (payload lenght indicator) + payload length).

Let's say the payload length is 1020 bytes. The message is initially received by the `codec` will have `readableBytes = 16 bytes + 2 bytes + 1020 bytes`. The header is read by the `decode` method and the remainder of the available bytes (1022) is then added to the `List<Object> out`.

If my understanding is correct, the remainder of the bytes will now be passed to the next handler which is `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` which will read the length indicator and pass the payload (1020 bytes) to the `SimpleChannelHanlder`, but I must be mistaken.

The `decode` method is called **again**, with the same 1022 bytes that was added to the `List<Object> out`.

In the JavaDoc of the decode method there is the following:

```
Decode the from one ByteBuf to an other. This method will be called till either the input ByteBuf
has nothing to read when return from this method or till nothing was read from the input ByteBuf.
```

Does this mean `decode` will be called until `readableBytes == 0`?

What will be the most efficient way to pass the rest of the message to the `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder`?

I assume the `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` needs a `ByteBuf` as input, so does this mean I need to set the `readerIndex = 0` and add a copy of the ByteBuf to the `List<Object> out`?

Any help/advice/criticism will be appreciated, I want to do this in the cleanest way possible.

Here is my `decode` method:

```
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    byte [] headerBytes = new byte[HEADER_LENGTH];
    in.readBytes(headerBytes, 0, HEADER_LENGTH);

    Header header = new Header(headerBytes);
    System.out.println("Decoded Header: \n" + header);

    //Set the header attribute so it can be used by routing handlers
    ctx.attr(ChannelAttributes.HEADER).getAndSet(header);
    //pass to next handler
    out.add(in);
}
```

NOTE: I'm reading [Netty in Action MEAP v8](http://www.manning.com/maurer/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean decode will be called until readableBytes == 0?

Basically, yes. A simplified view of a `ByteToMessageDecoder` looks like this

```
while (in.isReadable()) {
    int outputSizeBefore = out.size();
    int readableBytesBefore = in.readableBytes();

    callYourDecodeImpl(ctx, in, out);

    int outputSizeAfter = out.size();
    int readableBytesAfter = in.readableBytes();

    boolean didNotDecodeAnything = outputSizeBefore == outputSizeAfter;
    boolean didNotReadAnything = readableBytesBefore == readableBytesAfter;

    if(didNotDecodeAnything && didNotReadAnything) {
        break;
    }

    // next iteration, continue with decoding
}
```

So, your decoder will continuously read headers until the input buffer is exhausted.

To get the behaviour you want, you have to set the `isSingleDecode` flag to true:

```
class MyDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

    MyDecoder() {
        setSingleDecode(true);
    }

    // your decode impl as before
}
```

or

```
MyDecoder decoder = new MyDecoder();
decoder.setSingleDecode(true);
```

This will stop the loop after your decode implementation decoded something.
Now your `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` will be called with the `ByteBuf` you added to the `out` list.
The frame decoding works as you described, no need to add a copy to the list.
Your `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` will be called with the payload frame as the `msg`.

However, you won't be able to read the Header from the `AttributeMap` in your `SimpleChannelInboundHandler`
since the `ChannelHandlerContext` is a different one for each channel handler, the atrributes aren't shared.

One way to solve this is to use an event for this.
In your `decoder`, instead of adding the `Header` to the `AttributeMap`, send it as an event:

```
// instead of
// ctx.attr(Header.ATTRIBUTE_KEY).getAndSet(header);
// do this
ctx.fireUserEventTriggered(ChannelAttributes.HEADER);
```

Then, write your `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` like so

```
class MyMessageHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {

    private Header header = null;

    MyMessageHandler() {
          super(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void userEventTriggered(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final Object evt) throws Exception {
        if (evt instanceof Header) {
            header = (Header) evt;
        } else {
            super.userEventTriggered(ctx, evt);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final ByteBuf msg) throws Exception {
        if (header != null) {
            System.out.println("header = " + header);
            // continue with header, such as routing...
        }
        header = null;
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to send both objects down the pipeline and use a
`ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` instead of a `SimpleChannelInboundHandler`.
In your `decoder`, instead of adding the `Header` to the `AttributeMap`, add it to `out`:

```
// ...
out.add(header);
out.add(in);
```

Then, write your `ChannelInboundHandler` like so

```
class MyMessageHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    private Header header = null;

    @Override
    public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final Object msg) throws Exception {
        if (msg instanceof Header) {
            header = (Header) msg;
            System.out.println("got the header " + header);
        } else if (msg instanceof ByteBuf) {
            ByteBuf byteBuf = (ByteBuf) msg;
            System.out.println("got the message " + msg);
            try {
                // continue with header, such as routing...
            } finally {
                ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
            }
        } else {
            super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

The `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` simply ignores messages, that aren't `ByteBuf`s,
so your Header will just pass it (given that it does not implement `ByteBuf`) and
arrive at your `ChannelInboundHandler`. Then, the message will be decoded into the
payload frame and passed to your `ChannelInboundHandler`.

Comment: Thank you! `setSingleDecode(true)` is exactly what I need. But I can't seem to find the method when implementing a `ByteToMessageCodec`,  only a `ByteToMessageDecoder`. No matter, will split up the encoding and decoding processes. And thanks for the tips on passing the `header` to the next handler. I did however manage to set and retrieve the `header` by adding it to the `AttributeMap` of the channel by doing `ctx.channel().attr(ChannelAttributes.HEADER).set(header)`. Any disadvantages doing this?

Comment: Ah, yes, `setSingleDecode` exists only on `ByteToMessageDecoder`. As for the attribute map on the channel, I see no disadvantages, it's certainly a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to [knutwalker's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26614672/7311767) answer: I found an alternative way for those who use `ByteToMessageCodec` that can't implement the `setSingleDecode` method.

Read out the bytes by in.readRetainedSlice() like following.

```
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    byte [] headerBytes = new byte[HEADER_LENGTH];
    in.readBytes(headerBytes, 0, HEADER_LENGTH);

    Header header = new Header(headerBytes);
    System.out.println("Decoded Header: \n" + header);

    //Set the header attribute so it can be used by routing handlers
    ctx.attr(ChannelAttributes.HEADER).getAndSet(header);
    //pass to next handler
    int length = in.readShort();
    out.add(in.readRetainedSlice(length));
}
```

Ian2thedv concerned about the efficency of the copying of bytes, but it's inescapable when the `readableBytes` is more than your message length, you can't just out.add(in).